# List all numbers between 0 and 10^n containing repdigits in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, digits

In Google sheets How to get a list of all [repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit#:%7E:text=In%20recreational%20mathematics%2C%20a%20repdigit,666%2C%204444%2C%20and%20999999.) numbers between 0 and 10^n.

**Example**: We have the input **n** in `B1` set to 3 therefore our numbers are between 0 and 10^3 alternatively between 0 and 1000

We should get this list of [repdigits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repdigit#:%7E:text=In%20recreational%20mathematics%2C%20a%20repdigit,666%2C%204444%2C%20and%20999999.).

```
11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999
```

**Requirments**

- Less references
- Shortest formula
- Efficient processing
- If possible without lambda and its helpers

**Note**

If cell or row/column **limit is reached** is acceptable not to join the result.

---

**More examples**

| n | Output |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999 |
| 4 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999 |
| 5 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999 |
| 6 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999 |
| 7 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999 |
| 8 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999,11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444,55555555,66666666,77777777,88888888,99999999 |
| 9 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999,11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444,55555555,66666666,77777777,88888888,99999999,111111111,222222222,333333333,444444444,555555555,666666666,777777777,888888888,999999999 |
| 10 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999,11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444,55555555,66666666,77777777,88888888,99999999,111111111,222222222,333333333,444444444,555555555,666666666,777777777,888888888,999999999,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,6666666666,7777777777,8888888888,9999999999 |
| 11 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999,11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444,55555555,66666666,77777777,88888888,99999999,111111111,222222222,333333333,444444444,555555555,666666666,777777777,888888888,999999999,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,6666666666,7777777777,8888888888,9999999999,11111111111,22222222222,33333333333,44444444444,55555555555,66666666666,77777777777,88888888888,99999999999 |
| 12 | 11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99,111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999,1111,2222,3333,4444,5555,6666,7777,8888,9999,11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666,77777,88888,99999,111111,222222,333333,444444,555555,666666,777777,888888,999999,1111111,2222222,3333333,4444444,5555555,6666666,7777777,8888888,9999999,11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444,55555555,66666666,77777777,88888888,99999999,111111111,222222222,333333333,444444444,555555555,666666666,777777777,888888888,999999999,1111111111,2222222222,3333333333,4444444444,5555555555,6666666666,7777777777,8888888888,9999999999,11111111111,22222222222,33333333333,44444444444,55555555555,66666666666,77777777777,88888888888,99999999999,111111111111,222222222222,333333333333,444444444444,555555555555,666666666666,777777777777,888888888888,999999999999 |

Answer (score 0):

> This question could phrased like:
> How to get all repdigit, monodigit or numbers that consist of the same digit between 0 and 10^n

Use this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(n, REGEXEXTRACT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,BYROW(SEQUENCE(n), LAMBDA(r, TEXTJOIN(",",1,REPT(SEQUENCE(9),r))))),"11.+"))
       (B1))
```

[image]

**Explanation**

We are repeating each number in the sequence {1;2;...n} 1,2,...n times and joining with comma `,` and join all with comma `,`.

In other words:
For each number in `{1;2;...n}` [`REPT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134) once and twice and ... n times then join all with a comma.

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`REGEXEXTRACT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`BYROW`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) - [**`SEQUENCE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9368244) - [**`REPT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094134)

Comment: works only up to 10^103

Answer (score 0):

Repdigits are multiples of [Repunits](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Repunit) like `11`, `111`. We can easily create Repunits of `1` by `REP`ea`T`ing `1` and supplying a  `SEQUENCE` to `number of times` argument of `REPT`. Once created, just multiply them by sequence of `1..9` and `JOIN` them using `,`.

#### Snippet(for 3):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT("1",SEQUENCE(3-1,1,2))*SEQUENCE(1,9)))
```

Comment: works only up to 10^308

Comment: @player0 Well, number limit wasn't one of the requirements in the question, but thanks for making my device hang with your formula -_-

Answer (score 0):

not sure how serious you are with `n` but try:

```
={""; INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REPT(
 SEQUENCE(1, 9), SEQUENCE(C1, 1, 2))&","),,9^9)),,9^9))}
```

where C1 = 1000 -----> (10^1000)

[image]

and if you are brave enough, change 1000 to 10000 or 50000 :)

Comment: Seriously set  default C1 to 50 or so. Not everyone have top of the spec devices.

Comment: At n=1000 in [sublime](https://i.imgur.com/Vbp1T5I.mp4), at n=50000 google sheets resist a bit and [snap](https://i.imgur.com/4o94NjK.png)

Comment: @Osm How did you execute Google sheets code in sublime?

Comment: @TheMaster You wouldn't understand but something called copy-paste lol, is there a way to do so?!  execute Google sheets code with sublime? this would be nice

Comment: Me commenting why it [looks](https://i.imgur.com/yEpLSGX.png) like art @Player0 : because it's art 

Comment: @TheMaster There is a way using vscode see [this](https://youtu.be/lwxiEB-Mnys?t=1126)

Comment: @TheMaster with Intel Core i5 760 @ 2,80GHz, 14.42 / 1.46 Mbps juice, and ~450 opened chrome tabs I can run C1 = 9000 with no issues. with more, it Snaps! due to low network

Comment: @player0 `low network`. All calculations are done locally on device.

Comment: @Osm That's just Google apps script not formulae. I'm a Top user on [tag:clasp].

Comment: @TheMaster you meant to link this? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:8404453+[clasp]

Comment: @Osm No [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/clasp/topusers)

Comment: @TheMaster by "low network" I meant I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK1Qg.png and sometimes  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhTiO.png